# Wrap PyMC around Sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pymc

I thought that wrapping PyMC around various Sklearn models would be an easy win for estimating uncertainty. Here is a minimal example that reproduces my problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

# model
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

with pm.Model() as model:
    vals = pm.MvNormal(
        'vals',
        mu=np.zeros(2),
        cov=np.eye(2),
        shape=X.shape
        )
    phat = clf.predict(vals)
    yhat = pm.Bernoulli('yhat', p=phat, observed=y)
```

The error I am getting is

```py
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'TensorVariable'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/idlelib/run.py", line 578, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 820, in predict
    proba = self.predict_proba(X)
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 862, in predict_proba
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 602, in _validate_X_predict
    X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 565, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 879, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
  File "/home/galen/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 185, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My understanding is that `'TensorVariable'` is a placeholder for whatever data will actually be sampled. I guess the basic issue is that only operations found within Pytensor are allowed. Is there a reasonable workaround?